# Honda transmission problem

Tags: honda, accord

2003 Honda accord 4 cylinder original owner. About a month ago in rain when in red light and rain wanted to move because of little treads of tires the car skid and then some noises in the engine and  didn't move again. I towed the car to the drive way and its sitting there since. After checking youtube and other sources I have no idea what is wrong with it. I took out both solenoids check for malfunction and cleaned them. Never changed the transmission fluid but topped it when necessary. When I start the car and put it in any gear does mot move and make noise and the worst is when I put it back in park position. I want to flush the fluids tomorrow and put fresh one  as I heard it may help. Need your help people. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the final drive or driveshafts?

Comment: No I haven't. I guess I need to bring a mechanic to see it. I don't have much of experience in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your problems.

Did you check the link between the shifter and the transmission housing?

I would double-check the transmission fluid level.

If transmission fluid level is correct, read the fault codes with an OBD scanner.

There is a good article on Youcanic for [Honda transmissions](https://www.youcanic.com/wiki/honda-transmission-problems) that I would recommend that you take a look at.

Comment: I did not check that. The fluid was in correct range but I changed it and brought it to the correct level again and no change in the performance of the car. I have an OBD scanner but its not sophisticated and won't read codes related to the transmission. I have seen the article in Youcanic. Thanks for answering anyway

Comment: Read codes from the transmission control module. You mentioned that you have a scanner but it is not sophisticated. I am assuming, it can only read codes from the engine control unit. Meaning codes that trigger the check engine light. Those will not be very much help. You need a scanner that can read Honda manufacturer codes. Here are a few good scanners [worth checking out][1]. 
Your problem seems to be the valve body. A good scanner should tell you whether it is the torque converter lock-up switch or a faulty solenoid. 

  [1]: https://www.youcanic.com/wiki/honda-acura-OBD2-scanners